# how to prevent puppet to override any change you made on the linux server?

Tags: linux, puppet

i was trying to to change the timedatectl of one server from CST to EST. But everytime i made the change, puppet will override the change and bring it back to where it was after few minuite. How can i stop this from happen on that specific server? So my change remain. Thank you

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, but why don't you fix the puppet manifest instead of trying to work around it? Puppet is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 5):

> How to prevent puppet to override any changes you made on the linux server?

You shouldn't.

You automate your system management with Puppet (or any other system management tool) to prevent exactly that: sysadmins making manual, temporary and/or most importantly: undocumented changes to systems.

If that systems needs to be in a different state, then make that change persistent via puppet.

---

Now if you're manually debugging something, you can temporarily disable the puppet agent until you found the exact settings you want to adjust. That should prevent puppet from reverting any adjustments you're making while you're still making them.

But that should result in:

- an alert in your monitoring
- once the correct settings have been found, you update them on the puppet server
- enable the puppet agent again
- puppet wil revert most (if not all) changes you made while debugging while only allowing the system to keep the changes that you also adjusted on the puppet server